# Is it possible to create two RTCPeerConnections connected to eachother in the same window?

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

If so, do I need to do the normal candidate creation and negotiation, or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple tutorial here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample